# Retrieve sensor data from Azure EventHub Message with Azure Function (Python)

Tags: python, azure

I'm trying to send sensor data from a device to Azure IoT Hub and process it inside Azure Function. I managed to trigger the function when Azure IoT Hub receives data using EventHubTrigger.

However, I cannot find any way to retrieve sensor data.

The following data is sent from the device:

```
{"temperature": 27.5, "humidity": 63.0}
```

And the bellow is what I get from EventHubEvent body

```
{'properties': {}, 'systemProperties': {'iothub-connection-device-id': 'raspberrypi', 'iothub-connection-auth-method': '{"scope":"device","type":"sas","issuer":"iothub","acceptingIpFilterRule":null}', 'iothub-connection-auth-generation-id': '637374141338740275', 'iothub-enqueuedtime': '2020-10-04T16:21:15.0190000Z', 'iothub-message-source': 'Telemetry'}, 'body': 'eyJ0ZW1wZXJhdHVyZSI6IDI3LjUsICJodW1pZGl0eSI6IDYzLjB9'}
```

Source code for the sender and function app is as follows:

Sender/device (related part only)

```python
# Define the JSON message to send to IoT Hub.
MSG_TXT = '{{"temperature": {temperature}, "humidity": {humidity}}}'

client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING)

msg_txt_formatted = MSG_TXT.format(temperature=sensor_data["temperature"]["value"], humidity=sensor_data["humidity"]["value"])
message = Message(msg_txt_formatted)
client.send_message(message)
```

Function app （`__init__.py`)

```python
from typing import List
import logging
import json

import azure.functions as func

def main(event: List[func.EventHubEvent]):
    body = event.get_body()
    logging.info(body)
    my_json = body.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')
    event_data_json = json.loads(my_json)
    logging.info(event_data_json[0]["data"])
```

Is there any additional setting necessary to route IoTHub telemetry data? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you set up message routing for Device telemetry messages in IoT hub?

Comment: thanks a lot! I didn't notice that I need to add the custom endpoints..

Comment: thanks for clarification. I have added the answer based on your inputs.You can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `message routing` from `IoT hub blade`. If using Built in end point event hub, route the DeviceTelemetry messages to `events` endpoint else route to the custom endpoint i.e. in this case it is your event hub created in event hub namespace.